How to organize DB's structure
I have hardcoded (a lot of) phrases with some errors. After program did its work, it returns the result that I need to compare with one of the hardcoded phrase and choose the exact same.
I need to design database structure for it.
Right now I have this:

There are 2 example phrases at the right.
"Keyword" in the first table means that I need to find it in the second table. And then I look at column "Phrase" and check if there are other words in the same group in the origin phrase. If all of the words match then it is the exact same phrase.
Feels bad for me when I see same words in table "Words" (e.g. "the") and table 2 doesn't look good as well.
How can I improve my database structure for my needs?

A word can be in many phrases, a phrase is made of many words, so sounds like you rather need a many-to-many relationship: then consider that we cannot implement a many-to-many relationship directly, we need an intermediate table that rather contains FKs to the two initial tables... -- Try and look that up, then maybe ask if you have specific doubts: I am reluctant to just solve the exercise.
